# Linking to Paperclip URL from ActiveAdmin Record in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, activeadmin

I'm using both ActiveAdmin and Paperclip in my Rails 3.1 app.  In my user model, I'm using Paperclip so users can upload a PDF.  What I want to do is display a link to the PDF file, instead of seeing the segmented Paperclip fields in the table (ie file_name, content_type, file_size).

My user.rb model:

```
has_attached_file :letter 
validates_attachment_content_type :letter, :content_type => ['image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/png', 'image/gif', 'application/pdf', 'image/tiff'], :message => "Only pdf, jpeg, gif, tiff and png files are allowed"
```

My user.rb for ActiveAdmin:

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  index do
    id_column
    column :username
    column :email    
    default_actions
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass it a block. Something similar to:

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  index do
    id_column
    column :username
    column :email
    column :letter do |user|
      link_to user.letter, letter_url_path
    end
    default_actions
  end
end
```

Comment: thank you!  i just had to change the url to user.letter.url(:original, false)